# PHP - Chance of MySQL insert faliure?

Tags: php, mysql

Let's say I insert some data into multiple different tables.

```
Table A:

Name
Address
Location



Table B:

Name
Address
Location
```

What is the chance of MySQL say inserting into 1 but not the other if these we're 2 different mysql queries

I am trying to say, what is the chance of PHP or MySQL not inserting the data if all the data is completely valid.

Can PHP or MySQL mess up in any way and miss a query, especially if I am doing hundreds a second?

If so, how would I combat this?

Comment: No. There is no chance of PHP or MySQL messing up unless your code, ***which you have failed to include here***, is messed up.

Comment: If you are asking about doing 2 inserts and making sure that both work look into transaction.

Comment: Sounds like you need to look at *Transactions*

Answer (score 0):

Use a "database transaction".

A database transaction commits ALL or NONE of the operations you are performing, all at once.

If you have multiple `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, and/or `DELETE` operations that you would like to perform together, then you should:

1. Initiate a transaction.
2. Perform each one of the operations, one after the other.
3. Commit the transaction.

This way if something fails in between, NONE of them will actually happen until the "commit" is executed.